Facebook Sign-in not redirecting to the app after successfully login
In my iOS swift application I have implemented a Facebook Sign-in. It worked perfectly. But recently when user try to login it is not redirecting to app after user successfully login. Its stuck in the below view. After click cancel it will call to Login method with fbloginresult.isCancelled. I have updated the SDK also but nothing has changed.
Any help is appreciated.

